# Weird Issue with RDP from Windows to Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: remote-desktop

I've attempted to setup RDP on my Ubuntu machine (Running 16.04) so I can RDP from my other Windows Machine (Windows 10). Following tutorials online I've installed 'xRDP' when entering the IP of the Ubuntu machine I am greeted with a credentials screen.

After entering my credentials and clicking 'Ok' it goes to this very funny/strange screen? [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ub1HY.png)

Then after seeing this screen after about 5 seconds I get disconnected.

Fingers crossed someone has an answer to this, I've had a Google for hours but couldn't seem to find anything relating to it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set the colour depth on you client. Try setting it to 16 bits or higher manually, especially don't set it to 256 colors. I get a really weird display when I do that.